# Cannot compare strings in C++

Tags: c++, string-comparison

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

FILE *pfile;
using namespace std;

string temp_string;
string reserved[25] = {"AND", "CALL", "DECLARE", "DO", "ELSE", "ENDDECLARE", "ENDFUNCTION", "ENDIF", "ENDPROCEDURE", "ENDPROGRAM", "EXIT", "FALSE", "FOR", "FUNCTION", "IF", "IN", "INOUT", "NOT","OR", "PROCEDURE", "PROGRAM", "RETURN", "THEN", "TRUE", "WHILE"};


int main(void)
{
    pfile = fopen("hello.cel", "r");
    char cha, temp_token[30], temp;
    int count = 0, check = 1, i;
    cha = fgetc(pfile);
    while (cha != EOF)
    {
        if(isalpha(cha) || cha == '_')
        {
            temp_token[0] = cha;
            count = 1;
            cha = fgetc(pfile);
            while(isdigit(cha) || isalpha(cha) || cha == '_')
            {
                if(count < 30)
                {
                    temp_token[count] = cha;
                    count++;
                }
                cha = fgetc(pfile);         
            }
            count--;
            for(i = 0; i <= count; i++)
            {
                temp_string += temp_token[i];
            }
            cout << temp_string;
            for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                if(temp_string == reserved[i])
                {
                    printf(": RESERVED\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(": ALPHA\n");
                }
            }

            cha = ungetc(cha, pfile);
            count = 0;
        }
        fclose(pfile);
}
```

I have a problem with the comparison statement between the reserved[i] and temp_string strings. I cannot succeed printing "RESERVED", it always print "ALPHA".
To your knowledge, this is a program that gets each character from a file (hello.cel) and prints the type of each token.

EDIT: temp_token is a string were I temporary store words. This words have been made by adding characters at this line `temp_string += temp_token[i];`

Comment: elabolate your problem.Instead You can use if(temp_string.compare(reserved[i]) == 0)

Comment: Where is `temp_string` declared? I don't see it's declaration.

Comment: You neglect to show the definition of `temp_string`, presumably it's a `string` as well? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: This code is incomplete - you didn't declare temp_string, and I suspect the error in building temp_string.

Comment: I don't see the declaration of `temp_string`... What is its type?  You are declaring a string `temp`, is that it?  Does this code compile?

Comment: @Als Yes, i forgot to copy this certain declaration line in this post. I edited it now. It also compiles successfully.

Answer (score 0):

temp_string is not declared.

Have you declared temp_string as string?
For me it prints Reserved for keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The end of the loop gets a bit sketchy; you've got a missing `}`, and `ungetc()` sounds like completely the wrong thing to do. You need to change

```
            cha = ungetc(cha, pfile);
            count = 0;
        }
        fclose(pfile);
}
```

to

```
        }
        cha = fgetc(pfile);
    }
    fclose(pfile);
}
```

Also declare `temp_string` just before the loop that populates it (or, if you really want it to be global for some reason, call `clear()` at that point). Better still, initialise it from the buffer, after removing the pointless `count--`:

```
std::string temp_string(temp_token, temp_token+count);
```

or even better still, get rid of the temporary buffer, and build the string as you read characters:

```
        std::string token(1, cha);
        cha = fgetc(pfile);
        while(isdigit(cha) || isalpha(cha) || cha == '_')
        {
            if(token.size() < 30)
            {
                token.push_back(cha);
            }
            cha = fgetc(pfile);         
        }
```

And finally, only print `ALPHA` after checking all the reserved tokens:

```
bool is_reserved = false;
for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    if(token == reserved[i])
    {
        is_reserved = true;
        break;
    }
}
printf(": %s\n", is_reserved ? "RESERVED" : "ALPHA");
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/FWTgt) is a less broken version.